# Почему мой ip вычисляется легче при включенных плагинах анонимизации?

Tags: ip, proxy, dns

Доброго времени , заметил интересную вещь, при включенном прокси в firgate на сайте 2ip.ru вычисление моего ip становится в разы легче, если до включения он сразу показывал мой ip  и утечка была только от DNS.

Пробовал еще babylist, все те же проблемы

То при включенном firgate происходит утечка по DNS,  IP через Flash, Принадлежность IP хостинг провайдеру, Разница во временных зонах (браузера и IP), Подозрительное название хоста, Открытые порты web proxy, Открытые порты HTTP proxy

А вот при включении доп по Kaspersky security connection все идеально скрывается, но так же выдаются утечки по 80 порту и vpn + и VPN fingerprint

Почему открываются порты при включении программ анонимизации и в чем разница между плагинами анонимизации в браузерах и к примеру приложением от каспера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открываются порты при включении программ анонимизации не у вас на компьютере. Видимо они открыты на удаленном сервере, через который вы получаете доступ в интернет используя плагины анонимизации в браузерах или приложение от каспера. Повлиять на эту ситуацию вы можете только в ключе "не использовать сервис" или организовать свой собственный VPN сервер, на котором вы самостоятельно можете открывать или закрывать ненужные порты.

Разница как вы сами определили - это порты, открытые на серверах, через которые вы входите в инет при включении анонимизации.

Утечка IP через Flash лечится в настройках браузера.

Больше информации вы можете найти к примеру здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/263557/